# Грамотно ли составлено предложение после перевода?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> *Мы поклялись в том, что будем **слушаться и повиноваться** в трудности, и в лёгкости, и в усердии, и в лени, и в предпочтении других себе, и в том, что не будем оспаривать **дело** от достойных ему, и в том, что будем говорить истину, где бы мы ни были, не будем бояться **порицания порицателя**.*

Под **слушанием и повиновением** подразумевается верность руководителям. Это условие необходимо. Там, где нет послушания и подчинения руководителю, не будет ни порядка,ни успеха...

"... не будем оспаривать **дело** от достойных ему" в те времена руководство называлось "делом". В таких выражениях, как: "я спросил об этом деле", "если говорить об этом деле", подразумевается руководство. Так и здесь буквально говорится: "оспаривать дело от достойных ему", что означает: не оспаривать руководство, порученное кому-то из людей. Ибо в противном случае появится много претендентов, и в борьбе за руководящее место может разгореться конфликт.

"**порицание порицателя**" - это когда люди наговаривающие, клевещущие(порицатели) когда их наставляют наверный путь или разоблачают их. Порицатель - буквально "ложно обвиняющий"

Мне нужно грамотно составить предложение. Так же мне нужно подобрать что нибудь другое вместо:

1. ... в трудности, и в легкости.
2. ... в предпочтении других себе.

Comment: О какой правильности идет речь? Правильно по смыслу, стилистически или  грамматически? Смысл этого предложения мне непонятен, вопрос сформулирован нечетко. Нужно все существенно переделать или закрыть этот вопрос.

Comment: Пожалуйста дайте совет каким образом переделать вопрос я с удовольствием его переправлю

Comment: (1) По смыслу. Поясните смысл сказанного. Например, что значит "повиноваться в трудности",  "повиноваться в лёгкости", и т.д. Что значит "оспаривать дело от достойных ему", "бояться порицания порицателя". (2)Укажите, какую правильность вы хотите проверить: смысловую, стилистическую, грамматическую?

Comment: хорошо я исправлю. постараюсь только не закрывайте вопрос

Comment: Теперь это от меня не зависит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«Всё смешалось в доме Облонских». Но давайте разберемся по порядку.

Фактически весь ряд перечислений, который идет после слов «слушаться и повиноваться в» распадается на две группы, в каждой из которых эти слова имеют разный смысл.
В одной группе причисляются обстоятельства, в которых мы будем слушаться и повиноваться (в трудности, и в лёгкости, и в усердии, и в лени), в другой - жизненные принципы, которым мы будем следовать: предпочитать других себе, не оспаривать дело у достойных его, говорить истину.
А слова «не будем бояться порицания порицателя» стоят особняком и не связаны со словами «слушаться и повиноваться». Почему - непонятно.

Поэтому я бы советовал это предложение перестроить с учетом изложенного выше.

Теперь о деталях.

(1) «Слушаться и повиноваться» - плеоназм (одно и то же сказано разными словами). Не возбраняется в качестве художественного приема, поэтому спорить не буду.

(2) «Слушаться и повиноваться в трудности и в легкости» я понимаю как «слушаться и повиноваться, когда нам трудно и когда нам легко». Но «слушаться и повиноваться в лени» - это что? Слушаться и повиноваться, когда мы ленимся? Довольно странная мысль. Трудно и легко - обстоятельства, в которые поставила нас жизнь, а лень - сознательный выбор ленивца. Как можно слушаться и лениться одновременно?

(3) «Не будем оспаривать дело от достойных ему» я бы заменил на «Не будем оспаривать права достойных на их дело» (вариант: на то дело, которым они занимаются)

(4) «Не будем бояться порицания порицателя» имеет смысл «не будем бояться, что порицатель будет порицать нас». Скорее всего имелось в виду другое: «не будем бояться порицать порицателя».

Comment: "в трудности и в легкости" изначально "было и в активности, и в пассивности". вообще то там смысл такой: слушаться и повиноваться когда воодушевлены чем либо, и когда затруднены чем либо.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, «оспаривать от…»  — не самая удачная конструкция. И «достойных ему» — тоже. «Достойных его».

Comment: да я тоже задумался над "оспаривать от"

Comment: тут подразумевается что не будут оспаривать достойность тех или иных какому либо делу, а именно должности руководящих

Comment: Лучше сказать: не будем оспаривать дело у достойных его.

Answer (score 1):

Мы поклялись в том, что будем слушаться и повиноваться в трудности, и в лёгкости, и в усердии, и в лени, и в предпочтении других себе, и в том, что не будем оспаривать дело у достойных его, и в том, что будем говорить истину, где бы мы ни были, и не будем бояться порицания порицателя.

Я перечитала еще раз, и мне понравился этот текст. Это старинная речь с ее устойчивыми оборотами, не имеет смысла переделывать их на современный лад.

У нас тоже есть нечто похожее:  "Клянусь любить тебя в горе и в радости, в богатстве и в бедности, в болезни и в здравии...»

Comment: Это старинная речь? ===== Это — стилизация, потуги узбека на ниве стилизации и не на родном языке, которым он владеет не на должном уровне. Плохо, что уважаемый Авазбек не хочет понимать, что взялся за неподъёмный для себя труд. Согласен, переделке текст лучше не подвергать, тем более в режиме переписки.

Comment: Это перевод, при этом источник не назван (время создания и т.д.). Чтобы редактировать содержание, надо знать стиль автора, иметь хотя бы дословный (машинный) переводной вариант  и работать с ним. Скорее всего,  не стоило бы вообще браться за такую задачу.  Единственное, что было сделано, - это исправлены  явные грамматические ошибки.  Но ведь и грамматика относится к определенному историческому периоду или является  
 современной.- это тоже надо учитывать. Поэтому текст лучше не переделывать - в этом Вы правы. К примеру, слушаться и повиноваться - это плеоназм или художественный повтор?

Comment: Всё познаётся в контексте. Но надо представлять и задачу. Мы этого не знаем, и это замечательно. Достаточно уже того, что немного знаем Авазбека. И что  доцент тупой.